# longest segment of increasing numbers? (Java) (Array)

Tags: java, arrays

I'm trying to find the longest segment of increasing numbers in an array.

ex: array - {4.5 9.2 **3 5 6 7** 4.3 -2 8 8 8 3 3}
    output - {3 5 6 7}

This is the code i have written, and I know it's pretty bad but how i have written it and i will improve on it.

If you need more info just let me know i will post it after i get back.

```
        System.out.print("How many numbers will you enter?  >>> ");
        int numbers = console.nextInt();
        console.nextLine();

        double arrayList[] = new double[numbers];

        System.out.print("Type in numbers with spaces in between >>>");
        for(int i = 0; i < arrayList.length; i++)
        {
            arrayList[i] = console.nextDouble();
        }
        console.nextLine();


        double grand = 0, x;
        int l = 0, inOut = 1;
        int count = 0, count2 = 0; 
        double sum[] = new double[inOut];
        double fnum[] = new double[inOut];
        for(int i = 0; i < arrayList.length - 1; i++)
        {
            x = arrayList[i];
            grand = arrayList[i + 1];

            if(x < grand)
            {
                sum[l] = x;
                l++;
                inOut++;
                count++;
            }
            else
            {
                if(count2 < count)
                {
                    for(int k = 0; k < inOut; k++)
                    {

                    }

                }
            }

        }
```

Comment: You can not just dynamically resize your array.  TBH I do not even think that you need an output array at all, just append as a comma delimitered String

Comment: *System.out.print("Type in numbers with spaces in between >>>");* what does this mean ? Why do you want to do this?

Answer (score 0):

The problem which you are trying to solve is called `Longest Increasing Subsequence` and you can find more information with the proper explanation [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/longest-increasing-subsequence/).